# How do I create a Player for a Podcast using RSS Feed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, rss, podcast

I am building a website using html, css and bootstrap for my podcast, my problem is that I want to put a player of the podcast in the hero image part of the website so people can come and listen to my podcast at the moment of entering into the website. I want the player to use the RSS Feed of my podcast to always update the player with the latest episode, I hace been trying to look for a solution for that but I have found anything. I made an account here on stack overflow to reach some expert on this field to help me with this problem. I will attach some pictures of the design to illustrate my problem much better: [So this is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnOR1.png) I just need it to play the podcast and get updated every time I upload a new episode.

I put my code of what I have until now to see if is of help to resolve this. Thanks you all!

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.wrapper {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #07050B 0%, #18191F 48%, #2A2E34 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    margin-top: -60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.navbar {
  margin: 62px auto auto 141px;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  max-width: 60%;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: -45px auto auto;
  padding-left: 700px;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  width: 38px;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav a:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFE064;
  transition: 0.1s ease 0s, center 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
.nav a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 1px;
}
.nav a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#Component_6_1 {
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
}
#heroImage {
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 160px;
}
#Calltoaction{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.platfomrs {
    margin-right: 80px;
}
.platfomrs a {
    padding-left: 21px;
}
#calltoaction {
    background-color: #FFE064;
}
.titulo {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
#blog {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="author" content="Sealights Designs">
<meta name="description" content="El Podcast Libertario es el lugar donde aprendes a recuperar tu libertad de pensamiento, donde hablamos temas desde filosofia hasta economia y como tu, el individuo, puedes ser mas feliz con mas libertad">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">

<!-- Title -->
<title>Podcast Libertario - Inicio</title>

<!-- Links -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico/favicon-16x16.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css"
/>
<!-- Scripst --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent "> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/Podcast Libertario Logo.svg" alt="logo"/> </a> </nav>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#">Episodios</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#">Descargas</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white text-nowrap" href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <article class="conteiner-fluid">
    <div id="heroImage" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <aside> <img src="images/Copia de logolittle.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="Cover"/>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="http://cast.rocks/hosting/24334/85-Himno-destazandolibros.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <section class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <a href="#anfitriones container-fluid">
      <svg id="Component_6_1" data-name="Component 6 – 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="19" viewBox="0 0 35.604 18.918">
        <path id="Path_2055" data-name="Path 2055" d="M36.732,13.515,39.853,10H4.249L7.2,13.515l14.759,15.4Z" transform="translate(-4.249 -10)" fill="#ffe064"/>
      </svg>
      </a> </section>
  </article>
</div>
<section id="calltoaction" class="container-fluid">
  <p id="Calltoaction" class="d-flex justify-content-center">¡ESCUCHANOS EN TODAS LAS PLATAFORMAS!</p>
  <div class="platfomrs d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul>
      <a class="d-inline-flex" href="#"><img src="images/icons8-spotify@2x.png" width="63" height="63" alt="Spotify"/></a>
      <a class="d-inline-flex" href="#"><img src="images/icons8-browse-podcasts-96@2x.png" width="63" height="63" alt="Apple Podcast"/></a>
      <a class="d-inline-flex" href="#"><img src="images/google_podcast_icon_135536@2x.png" width="63" height="63" alt="Google Podcast"/></a>
      <a class="d-inline-flex" href="#"><img src="images/ivoox@2x.png" width="63" height="63" alt="iVoox"/></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
    <blog>
      <p class="titulo d-flex justify-content-center">BLOG LIBERTARIO</p>
        <div id="blog">
            <a><img src="images/Prometheus Justin Kendall's Prometheus -1.png" width="678" height="637" alt=""/></a>
            <a><img src="images/superficialidad iceberg.png" width="687" height="319" alt=""/></a>
            <a><img src="images/observacion de la realidad binoculars@2x.png" width="343.5" height="300" alt=""/></a>
            <a><img src="images/Lo que una amiga...L-1.png" width="343.5" height="300" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
    
    </blog>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: The visual design is unrelated to the issue of reading from an RSS. I'm not clear on what you are asking for, could you reduce the question so its laser focused on just one aspect ( the visual layout, reading from RSS, playing a video, etc)

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer, to answer you question what I am trying to do is building an podcast player that upadates everytime there is a new episode, I just need it to display the audio, title, description and date. Please do you know how to do it? I guess if I have the code I can just style it on CSS... Thanks have a nice day

Comment: Hey Edwin, what I mean is that StackOverflow is really good at answering specific questions, and you've got several nestled into one. Podcasts don't have anything to do with CSS or Bootstrap, and reading from an RSS feed doesn't have too much to do with CSS for example. Maybe just focusing on one specific part of that, rather than presenting the entire featureset. Like "How to get data from an RSS feed?" or "How to layout a call to action in bootstrap" or something.